# Obtain data of one Field and change how it is showed in List

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, listview, android-studio

Well, right now I have all the data from my db to my list without any problems, but I want to make the following : if one of the data is 0 - 1 then that item of the listview should show himself with another colour. Anyone has any idea of if that is posxible and which things I have to take on mind?

```
    String [] from = new String[]{manager.CN_NOMBRE, manager.CN_HORA};
    int [] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    cursor = manager.getData();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Obtain the activation data.. 
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseManager.CN_ACTIVADO));

        list.add(name);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        Log.e("test: ", name);

    }

    cursor.getString(7);


    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, cursor, from, to, 0);

    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    manager.cerrar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your `CustomAdapter` inside of there create an inner class`ViewHolder` and depending on the item current stat you can change it's color

Here is a [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEUqSn5Fqn8) tutorial that might get you in the right path